# Expected unqualified-id before 'public'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
public class Main {

static Node root;
static Node current;
static boolean directionRight = false;
static boolean directionLeft = false;

}
```

It gives an error on line 1. I cant figure out what's the issue.  Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Have added `C++` tag based on the error message.

Comment: What programming language *should* this be OP?

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration of `public class Main` should just be `class Main`. remove the `public` modifier. Also, `boolean` should be `bool` as rightly pointed by @HolyBlackCat. Right structure of your class should look like

```
class Main {
static Node root;
static Node current;
static bool directionRight = false;
static bool directionLeft = false;
}
```

Comment: Also, `boolean` should be `bool`.

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat. Included that as well.

Comment: That's assuming the program is supposed to be C++ (the only evidence being an error message that looks like one from g++, and a tag you added yourself). Otherwise, the answer is to use the correct compiler for whatever language it is.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, that just a strong guess. If OP comes out saying different language then I don't mind deleting the answer.